# Java Socket detect connection drop on linux

Tags: java, sockets, disconnect, tcpsocket

I am using this test program for socket in java.(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

I am running some tests with EchoClient and EchoServer programs running on separate machines.

If i run the EchoClient on a windows machine and pull the plug on the client network, the disconnect is detected almost immediately.
When i perform the same test with EchoClient running on a linux box (RedHat/Ubuntu) it takes 15 minutes to detect the network disconnect.

I do not have any socket timeouts set and am not using the TCP keepAlive option. 
How does the socket disconnect detection work in Windows and is there a way to replicate that behavior on ubuntu/Redhat?

Comment: I don't know, but this resource might be useful: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Comment: What is the network difference between the windows and the Linux machines?

Comment: I'm pretty sure windows has a disconnect event when the ethernet cable is detached.

Comment: To answer your question, you probably wouldn't find out until you sent something over the socket.  Most production systems usually solve the issue using a message protocol.  So say you (client) hasn't sent a message in the last 30 seconds, send a special message to ping the server and expect a reply back within some time frame, if the message doesn't come back (timeout), disconnect and reconnect the socket.